# yii JPhpexcel when when open it save file as file.xls.xlsx and can not open that file

Tags: yii, phpexcel

I have used `phpexcel extension` and its work fine, but when i save the file on my computer prior to open it, it works, but when i just download/open it, it froze!

E.g  when i select open with(Microsoft)...then file name is changed to `test.xls.xlsx` and it don't open but if i save it to my computer and then open then it works well with  `test.xls`.

```
Yii::import('application.extensions.phpexcel.JPhpExcel');
$xls = new JPhpExcel('UTF-8', false, 'My Test Sheet');
$xls->addArray($data);
$xls->generateXML('test');
```

I want to open file in both way 1) direct from download popuop (open with) and from my PC

How can i fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

To save in xlsx format you havet to go to php-excel.class.php and in function generateXML modify the line...

```
public function generateXML ($filename = 'excel-export', $correctFilename=true)
        {
                ...

                //header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"" . $filename . ".xls\"");
                header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"" . $filename . ".xlsx\"");


                ...
        }
```